# PostgreSQL returns: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'

Tags: python, postgresql, nonetype

In `Python` I use `psycopg2` to execute some commands for `PostgreSQL`. I want to manage if there are some empty cell in my database which is composed only by float numbers. I tried to use this code:

```
cur.execute("""SELECT my_number from my_table""")
 rows = cur.fetchall()
 for row in rows:
    try: float(my_number)
    except: break
```

But when it founds an empty cell, it returns this: `float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'`. So how I can manage this situation?

Comment: What is `my_number`?

Comment: use: my_number::float

Answer (score 1):

Catch the empty floats with this code:

```
if my_number is None:
 my_number = some_value
else:
 float(my_number)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the `my_number` variable in your code?

I think you might want to use `float(row)`, because that seems to be the number you are querying, since you're saving the numbers into `rows` and iterating over them.